# ACCESS VBA - Obtain Wireless Network Name (Connected)

Tags: vba, ms-access, module, wifi, detect

Is it possible to detect the users Wifi network (SSID) they are connected to via vba? in Access 2010

Many thanks
Max

Comment: You can do that with a WMI query from VBA - `SELECT * FROM MSNdis_80211_ServiceSetIdentifier WHERE active=true`.

Comment: Apologies for my late reply. just wanted to say thank you! but I'm struggling how to use this in a access query are you able to provide more details? Many thanks

Comment: If you just want to have the output of the function GetConnectedSSID() displayed in a field in the Access query thats simple: just write the function name in a field (with parentheses) and then each row will have a field with the connected SSID.

Answer (score 3):

After some more research, I found the following link: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?547916-List-available-wireless-networks-(using-WMI)-Help-pls

If you scroll down to post #19 there is a code fragment using Native Wifi API, I adapted to the following code fragment where Function GetConnectedSSID() will return the SSID of the currently connected Wifi network:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const DOT11_SSID_MAX_LENGTH As Long = 32
Private Const WLAN_MAX_PHY_TYPE_NUMBER As Long = 8
Private Const WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_CONNECTED As Long = 1
Private Const WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_HAS_PROFILE As Long = 2

Private Type GUID
    data1 As Long
    data2 As Integer
    data3 As Integer
    data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Private Type WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO
    ifGuid As GUID
    InterfaceDescription(255) As Byte
    IsState As Long
End Type

Private Type DOT11_SSID
    uSSIDLength As Long
    ucSSID(DOT11_SSID_MAX_LENGTH - 1) As Byte
End Type

Private Type WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK
    strProfileName(511) As Byte
    dot11Ssid As DOT11_SSID
    dot11BssType As Long
    uNumberOfBssids As Long
    bNetworkConnectable As Long
    wlanNotConnectableReason As Long
    uNumberOfPhyTypes As Long
    dot11PhyTypes(WLAN_MAX_PHY_TYPE_NUMBER - 1) As Long
    bMorePhyTypes As Long
    wlanSignalQuality As Long
    bSEcurityEnabled As Long
    dot11DefaultAuthAlgorithm As Long
    dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm As Long
    dwflags As Long
    dwreserved As Long
End Type

Private Type WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST
    dwNumberOfItems As Long
    dwIndex As Long
    InterfaceInfo As WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO
End Type

Private Type WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST
    dwNumberOfItems As Long
    dwIndex As Long
    Network As WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK
End Type

Private Declare Function WlanOpenHandle Lib "wlanapi.dll" (ByVal dwClientVersion As Long, _
                ByVal pdwReserved As Long, _
                ByRef pdwNegotiaitedVersion As Long, _
                ByRef phClientHandle As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function WlanEnumInterfaces Lib "wlanapi.dll" (ByVal hClientHandle As Long, _
                ByVal pReserved As Long, _
                ppInterfaceList As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function WlanGetAvailableNetworkList Lib "wlanapi.dll" (ByVal hClientHandle As Long, _
                pInterfaceGuid As GUID, _
                ByVal dwflags As Long, _
                ByVal pReserved As Long, _
                ppAvailableNetworkList As Long) As Long

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, _
                Source As Any, _
                ByVal Length As Long)

Private Declare Sub WlanFreeMemory Lib "wlanapi.dll" (ByVal pMemory As Long)

Public Function GetConectedSSID() As String
    Dim lngReturn As Long
    Dim lngHandle As Long
    Dim lngVersion As Long
    Dim lngList As Long
    Dim lngAvailable As Long
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim strSSID As String
    Dim strProfile As String
    Dim udtList As WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST
    Dim udtAvailableList As WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST
    Dim udtNetwork As WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK
    '
    ' Get a Handle
    '
    lngReturn = WlanOpenHandle(2&, 0&, lngVersion, lngHandle)
    If lngReturn = 0 Then
        '
        ' Enumerate the Interfaces
        ' (Note: this code only looks at the first interface)
        '
        lngReturn = WlanEnumInterfaces(ByVal lngHandle, 0&, lngList)
        CopyMemory udtList, ByVal lngList, Len(udtList)
        '
        ' Get the list of available Networks
        '
        lngReturn = WlanGetAvailableNetworkList(lngHandle, udtList.InterfaceInfo.ifGuid, 2&, 0&, lngAvailable)
        CopyMemory udtAvailableList, ByVal lngAvailable, LenB(udtAvailableList)
        intCount = 0
        lngStart = lngAvailable + 8
        Do
            '
            ' Populate the Available network structure
            '
            CopyMemory udtNetwork, ByVal lngStart, Len(udtNetwork)
            '
            ' Display the Data for this Network
            '
            strProfile = ByteToString(udtNetwork.strProfileName)
            strProfile = Left$(strProfile, InStr(strProfile, Chr(0)) - 1)
            strSSID = ByteToString(udtNetwork.dot11Ssid.ucSSID, udtNetwork.dot11Ssid.uSSIDLength, False)
            strSSID = Left(strSSID, InStr(strSSID, Chr(0)) - 1)
            If (udtNetwork.dwflags And WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_CONNECTED) = WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_CONNECTED Then
                'Debug.Print "Profile "; strProfile, "SSID "; strSSID, "Connected "; udtNetwork.dwflags
                GetConectedSSID = strSSID
            End If
            intCount = intCount + 1
            lngStart = lngStart + Len(udtNetwork)
            '
            ' Process all available networks
            '
        Loop Until intCount = udtAvailableList.dwNumberOfItems
        WlanFreeMemory lngAvailable
        WlanFreeMemory lngList
    End If
End Function

Private Function ByteToString(bytArray() As Byte, Optional lngLen As Long = 0, Optional boConvert As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim intI As Integer
    Dim intEnd As Integer
    If lngLen = 0 Then
        intEnd = UBound(bytArray)
    Else
        intEnd = lngLen
    End If
    For intI = 0 To intEnd
        strTemp = strTemp & Chr(bytArray(intI))
    Next intI
    If boConvert = True Then strTemp = StrConv(strTemp, vbFromUnicode)
    ByteToString = strTemp
End Function
```

Comment: This pulls the cached data but doesn't refresh/update the list.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have issues with GetConectedSSID function. It returns no WIFI even though I'm connected. So because of that I found this method.
You can use the command window "Netsh WLAN show interfaces" and parse the SSID.

```
    Set objReg = New RegExp
    objReg.Pattern = "SSID\s+:\s+(.*)"
    Set objMatches = objReg.Execute(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd /c Netsh WLAN show interfaces").StdOut.ReadAll)

    If replace(Trim(objMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0)), chr(13), "") <> "YourHomeWIFI" Then Exit Sub
```

If you want it to only run when at home.